# Tracing changes or Group by in SqlServer based on order of a column, like subtotals in Excel

Tags: sql-server

I have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Samples
(
    Id                  INT             PRIMARY KEY,
    A                   INT             NOT NULL,
    B                   INT             NOT NULL,
    C                   INT             NOT NULL,
    D                   INT             NOT NULL,
)
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.Samples
        ( Id, A, B, C, D )
SELECT 1, 10, 10, 10, 10 UNION
SELECT 2, 10, 10, 11, 10 UNION
SELECT 3, 11, 10, 11, 10 UNION
SELECT 4, 11, 10, 11, 11 UNION
SELECT 5, 10, 10, 11, 11
```

I am looking for a query which shows and traces change history of two columns A and B in this table.
The result should be like this:

```
1  10   10  10  10
3  11   10  11  10
5  10   10  11  11
```

because in records with Id 1, 3 and 5 we have a change in columns A or B.
I have an incomplete solution for this question:

```
WITH cte
AS
(
    SELECT TOP 1 1 HasChange, * FROM Samples ORDER BY Id 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT IIF(cte.A != q.A OR cte.B != q.B, 1, 0), q.* FROM Samples q 
    INNER JOIN cte ON cte.Id + 1 = q.Id 
)
SELECT Id, A,B,C,D FROM cte WHERE HasChange = 1
```

but I wonder if there is a better and simpler solution for this in SQLServer or not.
Furthermore, when I test this query with a large data I receive an error message like this:

```
The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion.
```

My question is:

1. Is there another solution for this problem and if it is, what is performance tips.
2. If I should use CTE how can I use it on a table larger than 1 million records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to use lag()

**Example**

```
Select *
 From ( 
        Select *
              ,Flg = case when concat([A],[B])=lag(concat([A],[B]),1,'') over (Order by ID) then 0 else 1 end
         From  Samples
       ) A
 Where Flg=1
```

**Returns**

[image]

Comment: thank you very much, I didn't know lag function in sqlserver. it is very useful and seems to be a complete and perfect solution for this problem. thanks

Comment: @JafarElahi Happy to help.  The window functions can be INVALUABLE.  Well worth your time to get comfortable with them  :)